# Table submission is null

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, xhtml, html-table, form-submit

In my project I have a form and one of its fields is a table. However when I submit my form, in my controller, my model corresponding variable to that table is null even I enter some data. How can I solve this? And what is the problem?

**My main view:**

```
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Car)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <p>
                @{Html.RenderPartial("FormTabs/FormLists/ListCars",Model);}
            </p>
        </div>
        //other code
```

**My table view (partial "FormTabs/FormLists/ListCars"):**

```
@using MyProject.Resources
@model MyProject.ViewModels.Car.CarViewModel
@{const string tableId = "tableCars";}

<table class="table" id="@(tableId)">
    <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @MyResources.Header1
                </th>
                <th>
                    @MyResources.Header2
                </th>
                <th colspan="3">
                    @MyResources.Header3
                </th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Car)
    </tbody>
</table>


<div id="initialButtons" data-tableId="@tableId" style="display: block">
    <p>
        <button id="btnAdd" data-tableId="@tableId" type="button" class="enable" onclick="addItem('@(tableId)', '../NewCarRow/')">
            @MyResources.BtAdicionar</button>
        <button type="button" data-tableId="@tableId" class="disable" id="btEdit" onclick="editItem('@(tableId)')">
            @MyResources.BtEditar</button>
        <button type="button" data-tableId="@tableId" class="disable" id="btDelete" onclick="deleteItem('@(tableId)')">
            @MyResources.BtRemover</button>
    </p>
</div>

<div id="btnsEditing" data-tableId="@tableId" style="display: none">
    <p>
        <button id="btSaveEdition" data-tableId="@tableId" type="button" class="enable" onclick="saveUpdates('@(tableId)')">
            @MyResources.BtGravar</button>
        <button id="btCancelEdition" data-tableId="@tableId" type="button" class="enable" onclick="cancelEdition('@(tableId)')">
            @MyResources.BtCancelar</button>
    </p>
</div>
```

**My DisplayTemplate:**

```
@model MyProject.Model.Cars.Car

@if (Model != null)
{
    <tr id='@(Model.Id)' onclick="selectRow('tableCars', '@(Model.Id)')">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { style = "display:none" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Owner, new { style = "display:none" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Owner)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Owner)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

**My new row view:**

```
@model MyProject.Model.Cars.Car

<tr id='@(Model.Id)' onclick="selectRow('tableCars', '@(Model.Id)')">

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "iEdit" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Owner, new { @class = "iEdit" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Owner)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: only fields that have been put into a for helper will be posted back to the controller (except display for)

Comment: @MattBodily through a function in jquery I add the "My new row view" code to "My table view" tbody. So it was supposed to be working. No?

Comment: the only way I have sent lists back to the controller is using an ajax call.  I have seen people on here send back lists when they put all of the fields into for helpers like I see you have.  If I had to guess the issue you have is the fields are on in the partial view.  Just to test you should put your partial into a form tag and submit just that form to see if the data is returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a solution: for each **'for'** helper I have on 'My new row view' and on 'My DisplayTemplate', I need to specify the **name** and **id** field. For example:

```
@model MyProject.Model.Cars.Car
@{
    string modelFieldInitialName = "Car[" + Model.Id + "].";
    string modelFieldInitialId = "Car" + Model.Id + "_";
}

<tr id='@(Model.Id)' onclick="selectRow('tableCars', '@(Model.Id)')">

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id, new { Name = modelFieldInitialName + "Id", id = modelFieldInitialId + "Id" })
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "iEdit" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, new { Name = modelFieldInitialName + "Name", id = modelFieldInitialId + "Name" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Owner, new { @class = "iEdit" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Owner, new { Name = modelFieldInitialName + "Owner", id = modelFieldInitialId + "Owner" })
    </td>
</tr>
```

and with this, the code can mapping the inserted values to the right variable and submit them